# Nginx proxy everything ending with /feed

Tags: nginx, proxy

I'd like to proxy everything ending with `/feed` to another domain.

For example I want

http://example.com/blog/feed  to become

http://api.example2.com/blog/feed

and

http://example.com/blog/categories/my-category/feed to become

http://api.example2.com/blog/categories/my-category/feed

This is what I got so far

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com

  location ~ \feed$ {
    proxy_pass api.example2.com;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_hide_header Content-Type;
    add_header Content-Type application/rss+xml;
    proxy_redirect off;
  }
```

Comment: how do you determine what gets ignored behind the `/feed`?

Comment: there will be nothing behind /feed. It will always be the end of the URL.

Comment: well according to you updated question, you don't need to rewrite any thing, your own solution should work, but replace `\feed$` with `/feed$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your own solution should be correct, but you need to use forward slashes not back slashes.

```
location ~ /feed$ {
    proxy_pass api.example2.com;
    # the rest of the settings
}
```

for who ever just downvotes without even saying any thing, I just copied what's [written in the documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass):

> When the URI is changed inside a proxied location using the rewrite directive, and this same configuration will be used to process a request (break):
>
> ```
> location /name/ {
>     rewrite    /name/([^/]+) /users?name=$1 break;
>     proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1;
> }
> ```
>
> In this case, the URI specified in the directive is ignored and the full changed request URI is passed to the server.

Comment: Url should end with `/feed`, not start

Comment: ok i didn't notice that, but now i don't really understand the pattern

Comment: I'm too. There is exactly the same question in serverfault

Comment: @Hedge, well then fix backslash to slash in location and add protocol to proxy_pass